# Print out number x in multiple of y * z

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to split 1680 number in between `40 * 42` partitions.

So now I have two sets, set one is `0, 1, 2, 3, .... , 39` and set two is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... , 41`

Which means for each number in first set such as for `0` in set 1, I need to print `0` for set 1 and `0 ,1, 2, ...., 41` for set 2 and then it will come for next number in set 1 which is `1` and for this, it will print 1 from set 1 and now it will print `42, 43, ... , 83` and then next number in set 1 which is 2, it will print out 2 from set 1 and then it will print out `84, ... , 122` and for last number `39` it will print out `39` from set 1 and then it will print out `1638 , .... , 1679` and then it will stop as our number was 1680.

Below is the code I have got. Firstly it prints out 0 from first set, then it prints out `0, 1, ... , 41` but after that it prints out 1 from first set and then it starts printing out `1, 2, .., 41` which is not what I want, I need to print out `42, ... , 83` for number 1 in first set.

```
for(int i=0; i< 40; i++) {
    System.out.println("i = "+i);
    for(int j=i; j< 42; j++) {
        System.out.println("j = "+j);
    }
}
```

It should print out -

```
i = 0
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2

...
...
...

j = 41
i = 1
j = 42
j = 43
j = 43

...
...
...
j = 83
```

and keep on going like this until 1679.

In short it has to print out each number in set 1 along with multiple of 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i< 40; i++) {
        System.out.println("i = "+i);
        for(int j=0; j< 42; j++) {   //dont do j=i
           System.out.println("j = "+(j+i*42));
        }
    }
```

I edited it, now it works. i tested it! Add 42*i to your j.

Comment: you guess? but i tested it!

Comment: This is what it is printing out `i = 0
j = 41
j = 42`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)
{
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    for(int j = i*42; j<(i+1)*42; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("j =" + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;

for(int i=0; i< 40; i++) {
    System.out.println("i = "+i);
    for(int j=0; j< 42; j++) {
        System.out.println("j = "+count);
        count++;

    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would help greatly as to how this piece of code works to solve/answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
            numberCount++;
            System.out.println("j = " + numberCount);
        }
}
```

It prints

```
output
------
1
2
3
.....
1678
1679
1680
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as you wanted.

```
int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("j = ");
            }
            System.out.print("" + count++);
            if (j < 41) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            if (j == 41) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```